# Accessing C Struct member from a different file(the main)

Tags: c

Checked couple of stack overflow questions/answers but none correspond to what I am trying to do. Here is it:

I have a c object file `myobject.c` containing struct type populated at run time (as initialised by main file having the `main()` function. Below is the skeletal structure of `myobject.c`:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t    ID;
    float       tempo;
    char        unit[10];
    unsigned long timestamp;
} prv_data_t;

static uint8_t prv_value(lwm2m_data_t* dataP,
                           prv_data_t* tempData)
{
    uint8_t ret = COAP_205_CONTENT;  
    //TO DO here
  .
  .
  .
   return ret;
}

static uint8_t prv_read(..paramList)
{
    //TO DO here
    .
    .

  //then call prv_value here
        result = prv_value((*tlvArrayP)+i, tempData);

    return result;
}
object_t * get_object(){
//this func get called by main.c to initialize myobject
}
```

Skeletal structure of the `main.c`file:

```
myFunc(mypar p) {

}

main(){

  //initialize myobject
  //.....

  //access myobject struct member here, pass to myFunc call
  myFunc(tempo)
}
```

The `main.c` initialises `myobject.c`. Now I want to access `tempo` a member of `prv_data_t`from `myobject.c`for some computation. How do I achieve such a task without exposing `prv_data_t` in `main.c`?

**EDIT:** here's what I mean by `main.c` initialises `myobject.c` and all other objects, please:

```
 /*
     * Now the main function fill an array with each object,
     * Those functions are located in their respective object file.
     */
    objArray[0] = get_security_object();
    if (NULL == objArray[0])
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create security object\r\n");
        return -1;
    }
.
.
.
```

The main file actually contains the `main()`function.

Comment: Put the definition of `prv_data_t` in a header file that is only included in `myobject.c`?

Comment: `myobject.c` is not an object file.

Comment: `prv_data_t` is a *type*, not an object.  But you access the members of an object of that type the same way anywhere that the type is in scope.

Comment: @melpomene I think it's just poorly worded

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say that "`main.c` initializes `myobject.c`"?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I edit my question to explain what I mean by "initialises".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid exposing your private data by doing:

1. Let `main` work with pointers to incomplete type `struct prv_data_t`
2. Implement getter-functions (and setter-functions) for members that you allow `main` to access

Something like this:

**a.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct prv_data_t;  // Incomplete type

struct prv_data_t * get_obj();
float get_tempo(struct prv_data_t * this);
```

**a.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct prv_data_t
{
    int         ID;
    float       tempo;
    char        unit[10];
    unsigned long timestamp;
};

float get_tempo(struct prv_data_t * this)
{
  return this->tempo;
}

struct prv_data_t * get_obj()
{
  struct prv_data_t * p = malloc(sizeof *p);

  p->tempo = 42.0;

  return p;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.h"

int main()
{
  struct prv_data_t * p = get_obj();

  printf("%f\n", get_tempo(p));

  // The line below can't compile because the type is incomplete
  // printf("%f\n", p->tempo);

  return 0;
}
```

So with this kind of code `main` only knows that there exists a `struct prv_data_t` but `main` knows nothing about the members of that struct.